# Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, hamiltonian, unitarity, time-evolution

I was reading Feynman's Lectures III's [Hamiltonian Matrix](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_08.html#Ch8-S5). There I found this property of Hamiltonian Matrix:

> The Hamiltonian has one property that can be deduced right away, namely, that
>   $$H^*_{ij}  = H_{ji} $$This follows from the condition that the total probability that the system is in some state does not change. If you start with a particle—an object or the world—then you’ve still got it as time goes on. The total probability of finding it somewhere is $$\sum_i |C_i(t)|^2$$which must not vary with time. If this is to be true for any starting condition $ϕ$, then Eq. (8.40) must also be true.

I haven't understood Feynman's reasoning for proving the law; how "the total probability that the system is in some state does not change" assure the validity of the property? Can anyone explain me Feynman's reasoning?

Comment: I think he is just arguing that, given that the time evolution is $U(t) = e^{iHt}$, by requiring the probability to be conserved one is requiring $U$ to be unitary, hence $H$ to be self-adjoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so, let's get this thing going right.

The property you're talking about is called by different names that you can google: e.g. that the Hamiltonian matrix must be *self-adjoint* (where the adjoint is the conjugate transpose) or *Hermitian*.

The easiest property to prove about Hermitian matrices is that they have real eigenvalues, for their defining characteristic $\langle H \psi| \psi\rangle = \langle \psi| H \psi\rangle$ combines with the property $\langle a | b\rangle = \left(\langle b | a\rangle\right)^*$ to say that a certain number (an "expectation value") is equal to its own conjugate, which is only true for real numbers.

How does this connect to probability conservation? The total probability is$$P = \sum_i C_i^* ~ C_i$$and the Schrodinger equation 8.39 that he presents is:$$i\hbar\,\frac{\rm dC_i}{\rm dt}=\sum_jH_{ij}(t)C_j(t).$$The conjugate expression must therefore be:
$$-i\hbar\,\frac{\rm dC_i^*}{\rm dt}=\sum_jH_{ij}^*(t)C_j^*(t).$$ Now let us just take a derivative of $P$ with the product rule, as:$$\begin{align}i\hbar \frac{dP}{dt} &= i\hbar  \sum_i \left({\rm dC_i^*\over \rm dt} ~ C_i + C_i^* ~ {\rm dC_i\over \rm dt}\right)\\
&= \sum_{ij}\left(C_i^* ~H_{ij} ~C_j - H_{ij}^* ~C_j^*~ C_i\right)\end{align}$$We now perform a dirty trick: we split this sum into its two terms and we **relabel** each part of the sum differently. In the **first** term we take $i \mapsto m$ and $j \mapsto n$. But in the **second** term we take $i \mapsto n$ and $j \mapsto m$. We then combine both terms together to find:$$i\hbar \frac{\rm dP}{\rm dt} = \sum_{mn}\left(C_m^* ~H_{mn} ~C_n - H_{nm}^* ~C_m^*~ C_n\right),$$and, combining like terms:$$i\hbar \frac{\rm dP}{\rm dt} = \sum_{mn}C^*_m~C_n  \left(H_{mn} - H_{nm}^*\right).$$The implication is that if we want $\rm dP/\rm dt = 0$ for all $C_n$ (total probability does not escape the system) then we **must** have that the parenthesized matrix is the 0-matrix.

Why? It's actually not too complicated to see. If we steal the $i$ from the left to define $$D_{mn} = -i \left(H_{mn} - H_{nm}^*\right),$$then we know for sure that $D_{mn}$ is Hermitian by construction. (Just take its conjugate transpose, I dare you.) [Because it's Hermitian, it is never defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix) and we can diagonalize it with real eigenvalues down the diagonal. Now either one of these eigenvalues $\lambda$ is nonzero, in which case we can use the corresponding eigenvector as $C_n$ above and we get $\hbar \frac{\rm dP}{\rm dt} = \lambda \sum_m C_m^* C_m = \lambda P$, violating probability conservation, or else all of the eigenvalues are 0 and this expression is the 0-matrix. But the 0 matrix has all-zero components in all bases, not just its eigenbasis, so therefore $H_{mn} = H^*_{nm}$ in general.

Comment: Hi, sir....couldn't contact(am suffering from measles!). Though most of the maths' operation I could understand, I couldn't comprehend why $\dfrac{dp}{dt}$ needs to be zero. Can you please provide a little explanation for it. Also, sir, can you please explain the line **total probability does not escape the system**? Why does _probability_ need to be **conserved**?? Thanks in advance, sir:)

Comment: @user36790 $dP/dt = 0$ because $P$ is the **sum** of probabilities for **all** possible outcomes, hence we want $P = 1$, constant over time. If an electron's total probability *isn't* conserved, then that means that sometimes, if we look everywhere for it, we don't find it -- which means other things like its mass cannot easily be conserved within the theory. It is effectively a commitment that, if we want to model electrons entering/leaving a system S, we're going to do quantum mechanics on a larger system consisting of S plus "electron reservoirs" that absorb/emit electrons.

Comment: I have queries, sir. Say, I have a state-vector: $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i c_i|a_i\rangle$. So, the total probability to find the particle in any of its base states is $\sum_i |c_i|^2$ which is always 1, right? Acc. to probability-conservation, the total probability remains the same i.e. 1, right? Now, suppose, the probability of finding the particle anywhere would be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi|^2 dx$ which would be 1 & again by probability-conservation, it would be same all the time. Just want to know, are $\sum_i |c_i|^2$ & $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi|^2 dx$ describing same thing or not?

Comment: Another one: I've understood from your explanation that in order to conserve mass, you need to have probability conserved. But I am not understanding why the concept of "probability-current" is needed; yes, we need probability to be 1 always & hence need to be conserved but how is it related to current? Why is the emergent of the concept of current??

Comment: In order to have a better grisp over the concept of  probability-conservation, just I am conjuring up what would happen if the total probability **decreased** over time from 1 to, say, $1 \over 4$. What would be the scenario then? How would it affect the possibility of being in one of its base states $|a_i\rangle$? Thanks in advance. I'll be grateful if you help me, sir:)

Comment: Well for example a spin-$1/2$ system has two states, "spin-down" $|0\rangle$ and "spin-up" $|1\rangle$. You could have it in the "spin-right" state $|+\rangle = \sqrt{1/2}|0\rangle + \sqrt{1/2}|1\rangle$ or spin-left $|-\langle = \sqrt{1/2}|0\rangle - \sqrt{1/2}|1\rangle$; if $H_{mn}$ has the structure $\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&-i\hbar\eta\\-i\hbar\eta&0\end{array}\right]$ then $a |+\rangle$ decays like $i (da/dt) |+\rangle = -i \eta a |+\rangle$ or $a = a_0 e^{-\eta t}$, while $b |-\rangle$ explodes. Starting from $|0\rangle$ the spin on the x-axis blows up like $-\sinh(\eta t)$.

Comment: If you just start in the $|+\rangle$ state, by contrast, the system simply asymptotically decays from spin $\hbar/2$ along the x-axis to 0, and the closer it gets to 0, the less it reads when you try *any* instantaneous experiment; your only hope is to rotate $|+\rangle$ to $|-\rangle$ and let the probability exponentially build up to large values again over time.

Comment: Thanks sir, I am continuing Feynman's lectures; really thanks for the help & hope you'll help If I'm in a problem in the lectures! Thanks, again, sir:)

Answer (score 2):

If that property doesn't hold then $H$ is not Hermitian.  This means its eigenvalues could be complex and the time evolution operator won't be unitary:
$U(t)U(t)^\dagger=e^\frac{iHt-itH^\dagger }{\hbar} \neq1$

If it's not unitary, then it will change the length of your state vectors which you're evolving.  Since the length of these($\sum_i |C_i(t)|^2$) vectors are the sum of the probabilities, your total probability won't be conserved.

Answer (score 1):

What he actually is referring to is the mathematical fact that in order for the standard norm (length) of $n$-tuple $[C_j]_{j=1,2,...n}$ to be preserved during evolution determined by the equation

$$
\frac{\rm dC_i}{\rm dt} = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \sum_j H_{ij} C_j
$$
where $H_{ij}$ is time-independent complex matrix, this matrix needs to be hermitian, i.e. obey the condition for all pairs $i,j$,

$$
H_{ij}^* = H_{ji}.
$$

This can be proven starting with the condition that norm squared is constant in time:

$$
\frac{\rm d}{\rm dt}\bigg(\sum_i C_i^*C_i\bigg)=0
$$

and using the above differential equation.

Feynman just rephrases this and uses term "total probability" instead of "norm squared", because it is common to interpret  $|C_i|^2$ as probability that $i^{\textrm{th}}$ eigenvalue of $H$ will be measured.

Comment: Actually, the matrix that multiplies $C_j$ has to be unitary. But the unitary evolution operator is $e^{iHt}$, which is unitary if $iH$ is anti-Hermitian, which happens when $H$ is Hermitian.

Comment: @KevinZhou, you're right! I need to edit this.

Comment: Sir, you've forgotten to write the "-" sign in the equation; I've edited it.